# Visual Editor and MediaWiki - Couldn't connect to server

Tags: docker, mediawiki

VisualEditor 1.32

Mediawiki 1.32

Parsoid 0.10.0

Error:
`apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http-error: (curl error: 7) Couldn't connect to server`

The regular editor works. The database works.

What is wrong? Whatever I do, it does not help me. I try manual install to Arch - always the same error.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mediawiki:
    build: .
    image: amediawiki32ve
    container_name: mediawiki_wiki
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8024:80
    links:
      - database
      - parsoid
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/images
      # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
      # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
      # the mediawiki service
      - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
  database:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      # @see https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/includes/DefaultSettings.php
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_wiki
      MYSQL_USER: pscn
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: example1
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
    ports:
      - 4675:3306
  parsoid:
    image: thenets/parsoid:0.10.0
    ports:
      - 8035:8000
    restart: always
    environment:
      PARSOID_DOMAIN_localhost: localhost:8024/api.php
```

Dockerfile to build:

```
FROM mediawiki:1.32

RUN cd /var/www/html/extensions &&\
    git clone -b REL1_32 https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor.git &&\
    cd VisualEditor &&\
    git submodule update --init
```

LocalSettings.php (together with automatically generated settings):

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'visualeditor-enable';
$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(
    'url' => 'localhost:8035',
    'domain' => 'localhost'
);
```

[image]

When click `Edit`:
`http://localhost:8024/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Strona_główna&uselang=pl&oldid=3`

`{"error":{"code":"apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http-error","info":"(curl error: 7) Couldn't connect to server","*":"See http://localhost:8024/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."}}`

And:
`http://localhost:8024/load.php?debug=false&lang=pl&modules=diffMatchPatch,papaparse,rangefix,spark-md5,treeDiffer,unicodejs|ext.visualEditor.articleTarget,base,core,data,desktopArticleTarget,desktopTarget,diffing,icons,language,mediawiki,moduleIcons,mwalienextension,mwcore,mwextensionmessages,mwextensions,mwformatting,mwgallery,mwimage,mwlanguage,mwlink,mwmeta,mwsave,mwsignature,mwtransclusion,welcome|ext.visualEditor.core.desktop|ext.visualEditor.mwextensions.desktop|ext.visualEditor.mwimage.core|jquery.uls.data|mediawiki.action.view.redirectPage|mediawiki.diff.styles|mediawiki.language.names|mediawiki.page.gallery.styles|mediawiki.skinning.content.parsoid|mediawiki.widgets|mediawiki.widgets.MediaSearch,UserInputWidget|oojs-ui.styles.icons-layout,icons-user,icons-wikimedia&skin=vector&version=0ixr96x`

And:
`http://localhost:8024/api.php`

`{"options":"success"}`

**UPDATE:**

Somewhere else I found that you need to set parsoid:8000 in localSettings.php and mediawiki:80/api.php in the parsoida variable.
From now on, I have a 500 error instead.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor#Troubleshooting
Few reasons. I do not know how to check.
I do not have php-curl in these containers. I do not know how to rewrite. There are no longer any errors in the addresses.

Comment: Would be there any hints in network tab in browser's developer tools? That is, which request fails? (as long as it is AJAX/REST issue)

Comment: I have added queries and what returns.

Comment: Do you see anything if you navigate to `localhost:8035` in a browser?

Comment: Also what does `/etc/mediawiki/parsoid/config.yaml` (Or whereever it is stored) look like?

Comment: Dylan Yes,  page with ""Welcome to Parsoid (...)".  
in config is url: localhost:8024 and domain: localhost. This is automatically generated by parsoid.

Look at update to question. Now I have a further problem.

Comment: @ŁukaszPolowczyk I don't know how docker works but assuming it is linux could you run `lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN` and let us know what the result is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set:
In LocalSettings.php:
`'url' => 'parsoid:8000',`
In docker-compose.yml:
`PARSOID_DOMAIN_localhost: http://mediawiki:80/api.php`

And done.
The addresses were guilty.